# Concatenate two WCHAR_T arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winapi, lpcwstr

Dealing with these insane strings and arrays is giving me a headache...

Here's my code so far

```
wchar_t mypath[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t temppath[MAX_PATH];

GetModuleFileName(0, mypath, MAX_PATH);
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, temppath);
CreateDirectory(???, NULL);
```

The first two windows API functions use the LPWSTR variable. The third uses LPCWSTR. What's the major difference? After I get the path for the TEMP directory, I want to create a new directory inside it called "test". This means I need to append (L"test") to my "temppath" variable. Can someone give me some tips on how to use these arrays. This is what makes C++ a pain. Why couldn't everyone just settle on one data type for strings. How is wchar_t even useful? It's so hard to use and manipulate.

Thanks guys!

Comment: The Win32 API supports C, which does not have nice wrapper classes like `std::wstring` in C++.  But since you are using C++, you can use `std::wstring` for your concatenation.

Comment: *This is what makes C++ a pain.* No it's not. That's what makes C a pain.

Comment: I guess you're right @chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PathCombine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx), eg:

```
wchar_t temppath[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, temppath);

wchar_t mypath[MAX_PATH+8] = {0};
PathCombineW(mypath, temppath, L"test");

CreateDirectoryW(mypath, NULL);
```

Answer (score 6):

> The first two windows API functions use the LPWSTR variable. The third uses LPCWSTR. What's the major difference?

`LPCWSTR` is a `const` version of `LPWSTR`:

- From [`LPCWSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx):

  ```
  typedef const wchar_t* LPCWSTR;
  ```
- From [LPWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx):

  ```
  typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR, *PWSTR;
  ```

> I want to create a new directory inside it called "test". This means I need to append (L"test") to my "temppath" variable.

Use a [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::wostringstream wos;
wos << temppath  << L"\\test";
std::wstring fullpath(wos.str());
```

or just a `std::wstring` (as suggested by chris in the comments):

```
std::wstring fullpath(std::wstring(temppath) + L"\\test");
```

to produce a concatenated version. Then use `c_str()` as the argument to `CreateDirectory()`:

```
if (CreateDirectory(fullpath.c_str(), NULL) ||
    ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError())
{
    // Directory created or already existed.
}
else
{
     // Failed to create directory.
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `std::wstring(temppath) + L"\\test"` be easier (even better if `std::wstring` is used in the first place)?

Comment: @hmjd great answer! I accepted the other one though, because it was simpler, but I still +1'd this!